# Load XML file. Start with current day

Tags: php, xml, date

I have a simple XML table with dates **dates.xml**

> ```
> <schedule>
>   <day>
>     <date>01.03.17</date>
>     <dayname>Thursday</dayname>
>     <htime1>2:00</htime1>
>     <htime2>3:00</htime2>
>   </day>
>   <day>
>     <date>02.03.17</date>
>     <dayname>Friday</dayname>
>     <htime1>1:00</htime1>
>     <htime2>4:00</htime2>
>   </day>
>    <day>
>     <date>03.03.17</date>
>     <dayname>Saturday</dayname>
>     <htime1>0:00</htime1>
>     <htime2>7:00</htime2>
>   </day>
>
>  ...
>
> </schedule>
> ```

I want to a load list of the next 10 days, beginning with the current day from today. I've found a way, to import the xml-table by using **simplexml_load**.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("dates.xml");
echo '<li>';
echo $xml->date . "<br>";
echo $xml->dayname . "<br>";
echo $xml->htime1 . "<br>";
echo $xml->htime2;
echo '</li>';
?>
```

Is is possible to start a loop, beginning from the current day? e.g. Today is the 2th of March. The list should be like this:

02.03.17
Friday
1:00
4:00

03.03.17
Saturday
1:00
4:00

04.03.17
Sunday
1:00
4:00

...

Do you have any idea, how to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by the simplexml_load_file function is an object of type SimpleXMLElement. This properties of this object can be traversed in a loop. For example you should be able to use the following loop:

```
for ($count = 0; $count < count($xml->schedule>day); $count++) {
    $date    = $xml->schedule->day[$count]['date'];
    $dayname = $xml->schedule->day[$count]['dayname'];
    $htime2  = $xml->schedule->day[$count]['htime1'];
    $htime1  = $xml->schedule->day[$count]['htime2'];

    echo '<li>';
    echo $date . "<br>";
    echo $dayname . "<br>";
    echo $htime1 . "<br>";
    echo $htime2;
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to put the list into a loop and stop the loop after 10 days. This works fine for me:

```
<?php
    $xmldata=simplexml_load_file("dates.xml");
    $i = 0;
    foreach($xmldata->day as $day) {
    if($i==10) break;
    $i++;

    echo "<p>Date: " . $day->date . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Dayname: " . $day->dayname . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Time 1: " . $day->htime1 . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Time 2: " . $day->htime2 . "</p>";
    echo "<hr>";
    }
    ?>
```

But now, I need to ask for the current date, to start the loop from value "date" from today, and continue with the upcoming next 9 days.

The XML table begins from the 1st March. But if it is the 6th March, the loop should skip the first 5 days, and start from the 6th of March.